# Conditionally format a row in kableExtra

Tags: r, kable

I have the following table in R using the `kableExtra` package. I'd like to conditionally format the last row in my table where I can change the background color of a cell to green if the value is positive, and red if its negative.

```
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)

data <- structure(list(Category = c("ICE BoA 0-3 Yr", "ICE BoA 1-5 Yr", 
"JP Morgan 1-10 Yr", "USD/ZAR"), `Global Financial Crisis` = c(0.32, 
0.26, 0.29, 0.08), `Taper Tantrum` = c(0.31, 0.43, 0.43, 0.14
), `Covid Crisis` = c(0.12, 0.57, 0.52, 0.29), `Entire Reference Period` = c(0.31, 
0.31, 0.22, -0.26)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

kable %>% kable(align = 'lcccc') %>% 
  kable_styling(font_size = 30) %>% 
  column_spec(1, bold = T) %>% 
  row_spec(0,  col = 'white', background = '#7c3042')
```

If I were formatting a column, it would be simple to do this with a simple `mutate` argument before putting my dataframe into `kableExtra`. Any idea on how to do this for a specific row?

```
mutate(
  `Column Name` = cell_spec(`Column Name`, color = ifelse(`Column Name` > 0, "white", "white"),
                         background = ifelse(`Column Name` > 0, "green", "red")))
```

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be accomplished with `cell_spec` and specifying `escape=FALSE` in the creation of kable.

```
data=as.data.frame(data)

gr=ifelse(data[4,]>0, "green", "red")

for (c in 2:5) {
  data[4,c]=cell_spec(data[4, c], background=gr[c])
}

data %>% kable(align = 'lcccc', escape=FALSE) %>% 
  kable_styling(font_size = 10) %>% 
  column_spec(1, bold = T) %>% 
  row_spec(0,  col = 'white', background = '#7c3042')
```

[image]